# How to install wkhtmltopdf Libraries?

Tags: 7

Drupal 7.59

I use Views extensively, and would like to add https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export_pdf module.

As per the Module documentation, a prerequisite is the installation of wkhtmltopdf Library (https://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which should result in the following structure :

- sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf
- sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf/scr
- sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf/scr/Pdf.php

But I don't find those files in the wkhtmltox-0.12.4_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz dowload, especially no Pdf.php

I am not a programmer, and thus not familiar with Libraries installation : any help would be welcome

Comment: wkhtmltopdf needs to be installed on the server - **phpwkhtmltopdf**, note the preceding **php**, is the PHP wrapper around that library. That's what Drupal needs. It's here: https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Comment: You install libraries module as any other module but to install a library that can be picked up by libraries module (and hence used by other modules) you have to put it as @Clive mentions above in this directory `sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf` and make sure the `sites/all/libraries/phpwkhtmltopdf/scr/Pdf.php` is actually there.

Comment: Thank you to both of you ; if I understand well, I just have to download, unzip and copy phpwkhtmltopdf to sites/all/libraries ? (Libraries Module is already in sites/all/modules). (BTW, Pdf.php is there, under src, not scr)

Comment: Clive : if you transform your comment in an answer I will be glad to approve it.

Comment: @Clive where does this library go in Drupal 8?